# How solid should old plaster be?

Tags: walls, plaster

I'm currently redoing the walls in my 100 year old concrete block home, which are made of horsehair plaster. I chipped away the cracked and crumbling finish layer, and got down to the scratch coat. My original plan was to leave the scratch coat as it is, and put a new portland/lime plaster layer over that. However, it seems that every single section of the old scratch coat is incredibly brittle. I'm able to scratch into it with my fingernail, and whole chunks were coming off while I was removing the finish layer. The scratch coat seems to be all horsehair, sand, and aggregate, with very little cement, so I'm wondering if it was just a poorly prepared mixture, or possibly the result of water intrusion over the years. If I have to remove all of it and get down to the bare block, that's fine by me, but I don't want to do extra work if I don't need to.

My gut tells me that the scratch coat plaster shouldn't be so brittle, but I just wanted to double check before I keep removing more. I know it's called a *scratch* coat for a reason, but from my understanding, you scratch the plaster after it has cured a little, but while it's still soft to create keys for the next layer. I just wanted to be sure I wasn't misunderstanding in the event that the scratch layer *should* be this soft.

I appreciate any advice, thanks!

Comment: Mine (plaster over wooden lath, 1890ish US) is harder than plasterboard, though there are places where it has lost its keys over the years.. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Mine, late 1800s, has a hard layer of topcoat skim over an inch of black crumbly dust that looks like it was dug from the garden. Touch at your peril. I've become an 'eggspurt' at injecting it with PVA if ever I need to go near it. It's either that or strip the entire house [13 rooms + 5 floors of landing/hall] back to the brick & start over… not going to happen. I redid one ceiling - 2 months of getting rid of the dust:\